# How set default value to xsi:nil in Soa

Tags: .net, xslt, soa

Soa xml result service comes with attribute xsi:nil="" in all element. 
This cause .net client generate "System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid Boolean value". When trying to cast with .toString().

Is there a way to set a default value to this attribute in the Soa?
Or ignore this attribute xsi:nill in .Net client?

Answer (score 0):

The SOA service is broken if it is returning xml like that- as per the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-0-20010502/#ref21), `xsi:nil` requires a boolean `{true, false, 0 or 1}` (and it's moot whether `false` is useful at all).

If you can't fix the broken service, you may need to treat the incoming broken xml as a string and remove the `xsi:nil=""` attributes before parsing it with an xml parser or deserializing it into objects.

Comment: Ok, I will try to look how to get out the xsi:nil="1". Thank you.